# Remove parent theme enqueued files in Wordpress child theme

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to make a child theme off the html5blank theme. I've managed to get my child theme CSS working using the following:

```
<?php
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
    function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'main-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/main.css' );
    }
 ?>
```

But the styles from the parent are still inherited. These are `style.css` and `normalize.css`. I have no need for these files at all.

So I've been told I need to use `wp_dequeue_style().` to *"remove parent enqueued files with wp_dequeue_style()"* and *add your hook with a later priority than the default 10. This is a third, optional parameter for add_action(). Something like 100.*

Unfortunately I'm really struggling with this basic task, I've tried but I can't get it working. I tried the following but obviously it's totally wrong!

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'main-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/main.css' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'parent-style-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', 100 );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'parent-normalize-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/normalize.css', 100 );
}
?>
```

Can anyone help with this? I'm sure it's straight forward but I don't have a clue!

Also, I'm guessing if I don't need the JS from the parent either as I'll use that in my child them, I guess I'd use the methods to enqueue/dequeue them?

**EDIT**

Is this more like it...

```
<?php

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles', 100 );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'main-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/main.css' );
    wp_dequeue_style( 'normalize');
    wp_dequeue_style( 'html5blank');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_scripts', 100 );
function my_theme_enqueue_scripts() {

    wp_deregister_script( 'conditionizr');
    wp_deregister_script( 'modernizr');
    wp_deregister_script( 'html5blankscripts');

    wp_register_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.12.0'); // Custom scripts
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); // Enqueue it!

    wp_register_script('responsive-nav', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/responsive-nav.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0'); // Custom scripts
    wp_enqueue_script('responsive-nav'); // Enqueue it!

    wp_register_script('uniform-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.uniform.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0'); // Custom scripts
    wp_enqueue_script('uniform-js'); // Enqueue it!

    wp_register_script('main-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0'); // Custom scripts
    wp_enqueue_script('main-js'); // Enqueue it!
}

?>
```

Comment: Looks like you're passing the third parameter to the wrong function.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I'm a total newbie with this stuff. Don't mind admitting I don't have a clue! I've added some more code under "EDIT", is that any better? I'm not on a machine to test it but will this evening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instructions were simply telling you to change this...

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
```

into this...

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles', 100 );
```

The full method call is...

```
add_action( string $tag, callable $function_to_add, int $priority = 10, int $accepted_args = 1 )
```

Only the first two are required, the others have defaults they will use in case you leave them blank.

Also, to dequeue, you only need the name of the parent identifier, not all of the file details.

```
wp_dequeue_style( 'name-of-identifier-in-parent-theme' );
```

It looks like you put the priority on the wrong function call.

And Yes, you can dequeue javascript files as well using this method.

Comment: I've added example code to the original post under "EDIT". Does that look better?

Comment: I did have the CSS and JS in the same `add_action` but I didn’t know if it was best to have them separated? Or should the deregister/dequeue also be split into their own actions away from the enqueued opjects, so only they have a priority set?

Comment: @user1406440 Anything that doesn't conflict can be loaded with the default priority. "Best" would be to separate the items you need loaded later with a nice clear comment on why they are separated from the rest so that 6 months from now, you (or someone else) can know why it was done that way.

Comment: Just to be sure, the reason I need to set a priority is to ensure my `dequeue` overwrites the same `enqueued` files in the parent theme? So they could have the priority and then more my child stylesheet into another action without priority? And presumably I'd that that with the javascript as well. So I'd have x4 `add_action` in total?